# Installing SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to install sfdx on my windows 64 to create lwc, I have VS code with salesforce extension and lwc extension. I downloaded sfdx cli from here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli

After installing cli, I setup the system variables to point to salesforce cli\bin. Now when I am going to VS code terminal and use the command sfdx plugins I get the message "no plugins installed", if I try to update the cli with sfdx update I get the error "S3 host is not reachable.". I am able to check the version with sfdx -v and the version is "sfdx-cli/6.51.1-ba7205094b (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4".

Am I missing any step?

Thanks

Comment: Also, executing the sfdx commands takes 10 mins to execute.

Comment: Ok. I was able to figure this out ... the slowness and the other issue was happening due to the proxy network I was on. I am on a direct connection now and CLI is working properly. But now I am getting "command sfdx.force.project.create not found".

Comment: [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244118/command-sfdx-force-lightning-lwc-create-not-found) question may help

Comment: Thanks I followed the thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244118/command-sfdx-force-lightning-lwc-create-not-found and re installed vscode and the plugins, it is working now.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue "S3 host is not reachable" when i tried to install it in my office network (which is on proxy), so i tried to connect to a normal network (without proxy) and i was able to install it.

How are you "creating the project" using command line of directly from vscode plugin, I think there should be an issue with class path for CLI

Comment: I am running the command "sfdx force:project:create --projectname " from vscode terminal and it creates a project. But if i execute sfdx: create project I get the error.